# How to import file from other folder in java?

Tags: java, macos, compiler-errors, directory, classpath

I have just started learning java, so struggling in very basics. The problem i am facing currently is "cannot find symbol : class Ques". I have resolved this issue when i was accessing package from parent directory through CLASSPATH export. Now problem is i am trying to access sub-directory from sub-driectroy like this:

```
family.of.adam(has)/
father.java
WifeOne(sub-direc)/wifeone.java,ChildFromWifeOne.java
WifeTwo(sub-direc)/wifetwo.java,ChildFromWifeTwo.java
```

Now what i am trying to do is from wifetwo.java i am accessing wifeone.java. I have tried importing (wifeone)like this:

```
import family.of.adam.WifeOne.*; 
import WifeOne.*;
```

In both cases it failed to import and same error occured which i mentioned above.

I have also tried solution provided in this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2476149/java-import-from-other-directory) but this effects classpath of WifeOne this is what i think because when i -cp method it starts showing errors related to wifeone.

I am using normal texteditor, compiling through terminal and using mac. Kindly brief me what mistake i am doing.

Answer (score 0):

Assume src is your base folder(place you compile and run the program).

src/family/of/adam/FirstWife.java

if so you need to define the package startmetn the fist line of the FirstWife.java file.

```
package family.of.adam;
```

Then,If the second java file in the,

src/Main.java

In Main.java file  you need to define the import statement for user the FirstWife.java class.

```
import family.of.adam.FirstWife;
```

Comment: I think u didnt got the point. let me explain, through my main directory which is father.java has no error in it. Error occurs when i try to use wifeone which has directory family.of.adam/WifeOne/wifeone.java in WifeTwo/wiifetwo.java. In father.java i am simply doing import WifeOne:* & WifeTwo:* and it is working fine

Comment: try to user only  import family.of.adam.WifeOne.wifeone

Comment: There is some issue with classpath, i guess!

Comment: already tried, hard luck it says: package family.of.adam.WifeOne does not exist import family.of.adam.WifeTwo.*;